# Understanding Standard Deviation for non-normally distributed data

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

On a normal distribution curve, **standard deviation** tells us how much data fall in each group around the mean, according to empirical law.

So, for example of SD = 14 and sample mean($\bar{x}$) = 50, as shown in figure below:
[image]
If the data is normally distributed, 68.2% of the data will be around the mean inside SD units on each side to mean.

Real data is hardly normally distributed, so how do I interpret Standard Deviation values I get from software, for example, `numpy.std` of Python?

Comment: yes, I didn't check that question and it didn't show up in suggestions when I was even writing the title of the question. my question is a duplicate of that question.